# Creating a module for python2 and python3 with SWIG

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, swig

I have a task in which I have to write the Python bindings for an existing C++ library. Since SWIG have support for not only Python but also for languages like Java and Perl, I am using SWIG. I am relatively new in SWIG so I have a doubt. I want my python library to be supportable under Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. But I don't have any idea regarding how to do this. So if anyone can suggest me. Any help would be appreciated. You can ask me for more details if you want.

What I have tried so far.

This is my code file.

```
/* example.c file */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int my_mod(int n, int m) {
      return n % m;
}

int sieve(int number) {
    int* arr = malloc(sizeof (int) * (number + 10));
    int* prime = malloc(sizeof (int) * (number + 10));
    /* printf("Size of arr: %lu", sizeof(arr));
      printf("Size of int: %lu", sizeof(int)); */
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(int) * (number + 10));
    int counter = 0;
    prime[counter++] = 2;
    arr[0] = arr[1] = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= number; i += 2) {
        if (!arr[i]) {
            for (int j = i + i; j < number; j += i) {
            arr[j] = 1;
        }
    }
  }
  for (int i = 3; i < number; i += 2)
      if (!arr[i])
  prime[counter++] = i;
  // free(arr);
  // free(prime);
  return counter;
}
```

And my interface file is

```
/* example.i */
%module example
%{
      #include "stdio.h"
      #include "stdlib.h"
      #include "string.h"
      extern int my_mod(int n, int m);
      extern int sieve(int number);
%}

extern int my_mod(int n, int m);
extern int sieve(int number);
```

My steps for compilation

```
swig -python example.i
gcc -fpic -c example.c example_wrap.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3)
gcc  -shared  example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

In above compilation format module is working fine with python3 but failing in python2 with error log as

```
ImportError: ./_example.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat
```

And if I use below compilation commands

```
swig -python example.i
gcc -fpic -c example.c example_wrap.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python2)
gcc  -shared  example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

Than module is working with python2 but when I try to import in python3 than error message is

```
ImportError: /home/deepanshu/env/swig/env/src/deep/_example.so: undefined symbol: PyInstance_Type
```

I am sure than the error is because `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs pythonX)` I am specifying version at place of X but how can I make sure my module works with both the Python versions?

I tried `-py3` flag of swig, but I wasn't able to make module work for both of the Python version with above specified flag.

Comment: You cannot link to both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x at the same time. If you want to support both versions, you need to executables and introduce a branch on Python version in the generated Python file.

Answer (score 0):

C extension don't work the same way in python3 vs python2.  This link can help you identify what you need to do on the C level to have the library work for both python 2 and 3 (not using swig). http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html

Using Swig, what I would do is make use of the pip wheels naming convention :
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#packaging-your-project

Doing so, I would package the library for python3 and make the package follow the wheel naming standard ("https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#id1" "py3-none-any") and then make the library for Python2 and package it using the same strategy("py2-none-any").  then you can upload it to Pypi and pip would know that it need to use the py2 for python2 and py3 for python3.